# Laptop app communication with mobile app using local and online databases

Tags: flutter, firebase, sqflite, local-database

I'm currently learning by myself how to develop apps with flutter and dart. So far, I have created a mobile (android) app for bank accounts, just for my wife and I. The apps on both phones communicate via firebase (for current amounts, adding new transactions and listing awaiting transactions).
What I'd like to do now is creating an app to be used on my laptop (a desktop app or a web app, that I'd use only locally in chrome) to on one hand communicate with the mobile apps via firebase, and on the other hand keep track of previous transactions via a local database.
The problem is that firebase seems to not work for desktop apps (yet), and that sqflite (that I was thinking of using) seems to not work on web apps (yet).
Of course I could only use firebase on a web app, I don't think I'd have to eventually pay something, but I'd like to keep the previous transactions locally...
Would you have any suggestions ? How would you do that ? (please keep in mind that I'm a beginner ;D )

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you think Firebase doesn't work on desktops? I run firebase (apps) all of the time on my Mac; XCode, Swift is fully supported as well as other platforms. There is [FlutterFire for windows](https://invertase.io/blog/announcing-flutterfire-desktop). And the entire REST API is platform agnostic so that can run on anything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jay. I naively tried to run my mobile app on windows via vs code, and it didn't work (again, I'm a newbie). then I checked on the net and saw that firebase worked only for mac, I didn't dig deeper. With your comment I also came across firedart, I don't know the difference with flutterfire, but I'll dig into that. Thanks again.